# SpriteKit SKSpriteNodes do not seem to be anti-aliased

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm creating a SpriteKit Game for OSX (not iOS) and my images are really jagged. This occurs whether I scale the image or not. I also tried with SKTexture Filtering Mode thing, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
CGPoint location = [theEvent locationInNode:self];
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"key"];
sprite.position = location;
[self addChild:sprite];
```

[image: key image]

Here's what it looks like in a sprite kit project:
[image]

Comment: can you post the code and the images?  it sounds like it's a problem with the assets if scaling has no impact.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. After closer inspection it's definitely my assets. I create my assets in Pixelmator. Any idea what the ideal DPI is for assets?

Comment: I added code up top. It is a 200x200px image and it becomes pixelated once I run my project. If you look at the image above, it does not look pixelated. Also, the project shrinks the image a lot. I messed around with the amount of DPI that I created the asset with and that seems to change the size of the image when rendered in sprite kit.

Comment: The size change when you change the DPI is probably caused by the tool you are using.  For retina graphics you'll probably want to match the display (220 PPI for retina MBP)  In PixelMator you can change the density under Image > Image Size > Resolution

Comment: Ok. What would be the DPI for iMacs or non-retina MBPs?

Comment: I would just use the same (high) DPI for everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57943/discussion-between-02fentym-and-joshua-smith).